# Can't update name in mongo using PUT in node express

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am having trouble updating a name in mongodb. The name is first saved by the user in a variable and passed into a function like this: putAjax(editName)  Then it goes to the function here:

```js
function putAjax(editName) {
    $.ajax({
            type: "PUT",
            url: "/items/"+ editName,
            data: editName,
            dataType: 'json',
        })
        .done(function(result) { 
            console.log("result:", result);
            console.log("data successfully saved:");
        })
        .fail(function(jqXHR, error, errorThrown) {
            console.log(jqXHR);
            console.log(error);
            console.log(errorThrown);
        });
};
```

I can console.log(result) and I can see the edited name so I assumed that the edit took place.  Finally it makes the call to app.put on the server:

```js
app.put('/items/:name', function(req, res) {
    Item.find(req.params.name, function(err, items) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(404).json({
                message: 'Internal Server Error'
            });
        }

       Item.findOneAndUpdate({
            name: req.params.name
        }, {
            $set: {
                name: req.params.name
            }
        }, { new: true },
        function () {
            res.json(items);
        });
    });
});
```

This is where the update doesn't seem to happen.  When I use mongo shell, the one document I have still continues to have the same name and not the edited name.  The confusing part is, why does console.log(result) show me the edited name then. I would really appreciate any help on this.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't passing a unique key to the database query. You're intention is to change the name stored in the database for an existing record but you're not doing this. Instead you are attempting to find a record that matches the new name value and you always return the value you have sent to the server.

Instead you need to pass a unique identifier with the AJAX request, using the URL makes the most sense.

```
function putAjax(id, editName) {
  var payLoad = { name: editName };
  $.ajax({
    type: "PUT",
    url: "/items/"+ id,
    data: payLoad,
    dataType: 'json',
  })
  .done(function(result) { 
    console.log("result:", result);
    console.log("data successfully saved:");
  })
  .fail(function(jqXHR, error, errorThrown) {
    console.log(jqXHR);
    console.log(error);
    console.log(errorThrown);
  });
};
```

Server side code:

```
app.put('/items/:id', function(req, res) {
  var data = req.body; // data should be validated
  Item.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.params.id }
    , { $set: data }
    , { returnOriginal: false }
    , function (err, result) {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(500).json({
          message: 'Internal Server Error.'
        });
      }
      return res.json(result);
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: thanks for pointing that out.  I've been at this all day and I can't figure out how to pass in the original value to search for it in the database.  Would it be passed in here?

app.put('/items/:name', function(req, res, data)

And my ajax on the client side would be:

 var oldName = { "name": oldName };
 $.ajax({
            type: "PUT",
            url: "/items/"+ oldName,
            data: oldName,
            dataType: 'json',
        })

Comment: Dan, thank you, it's working now!  But just in case someone else might be looking for something similar, for my case, I had to change the following code to make it work : Item.findOneAndUpdate({ name: req.params.id } , { $set: { name: data.name }}.